# Regular expression to replace words preserving spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to develop a function in javascript that get a phrase and processes each word, preserving whiteSpaces. It would be something like this:

```
properCase('  hi,everyone   just  testing') => '  Hi,Everyone   Just  Testing'
```

I tried a couple of regular expressions but I couldn't find the way to get just the words, apply a function, and replace them without touching the spaces.

I'm trying with

```
'  hi,everyone   just  testing'.match(/([^\w]*(\w*)[^\w]*)?/g, 'x')
["  hi,", "everyone   ", "just  ", "testing", ""]
```

But I can't understand why are the spaces being captured. I just want to capture the (\w*) group. also tried with `/(?:[^\w]*(\w*)[^\w]*)?/g` and it's the same...

Comment: Try using word boundaries `\b\w+\b`

Comment: both elclanrs and ooga are correct! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like

```
'  hi,everyone   just  testing'.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
```

If you want to process each word, you can use

```
'  hi,everyone   just  testing'.replace(/\w+/g, function(word) {
    // do something with each word like
    return word.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: Yeap, your code works great, but ProperCase was just a simplified example, I need to run a function on the whole word, not just the letter, anyway +1 because I wasn't clear enough...

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to process each word.

Comment: Great, I even noticed that with just \w+ is enough, no need for the word boundaries markers, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you use the global modifier (`g`), then the capture groups are basically ignored. The returned array will contain every match of the whole expression. It looks like you just want to match consecutive word characters, in which case `\w+` suffices:

```
>>> '  hi,everyone   just  testing'.match(/\w+/g)
["hi", "everyone", "just", "testing"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Felix, your answer is correct. I gave it to Michal because he answered first.

Comment: @opensas: so you did not want to preserve whitespace??

Answer (score 1):

See here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgE4W/2/)**

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(match)
{
    return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.slice(1);
}

var myRe = /\b(\w+)\b/g;
var result = "hi everyone,     just testing".replace(myRe,capitaliseFirstLetter);
alert(result);
```

Matches each word an capitalizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear about what you're really after.  *Why is your regex not working?* Or *how to get it to work?*  Here's a way to extract words and spaces in your sentence:

```
var str   = '  hi,everyone   just  testing';
var words = str.split(/\b/);   // [" ", "hi", ",", "everyone", " ", "just", " ", "testing"]
words     = word.map(function properCase(word){ 
                        return word.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
var sentence = words.join(''); // back to original
```

***Note:** When doing any string manipulation, `replace` will be faster, but `split`/`join` allows for cleaner, more descriptive code.*